# É possível capturar a origem de um arquivo arrastado do computador?

Tags: php, javascript, ecmascript-5

Queria enviar o path da imagem a partir do evento de "drop":

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload = function() {

    var dropZone = document.getElementById('box_paper');

    function handleFileSelect(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        dropZone.classList.add('is-dragging');

       var form = $('#upload'); 

       // **************************************************************
        var items  = event.dataTransfer.items;      // -- Items
       //SÓ PRECISO PEGAR A ORIGEM DO ARQUIVO, NÃO O BASE64 DA IMAGEM
       //E COLOCAR NO INPUT FILE...
       //MODELO 1 (comentado por aí) = ISSO NÃO FUNCIONOU... ???? ******
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            // Get the dropped item as a 'webkit entry'.
            var entry = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();

            console.log('items',items[i]);

            // Get the same dropped item, but as a File.
            var file = items[i].getAsFile();

            console.log(file);

            if (entry.isDirectory) {

                //ISSO SERIA O PATH DA IMAGEM SENDO ATRIBUIDO NO FORMULÁRIO, #SOQUENAO
                form.find('[file]').attr('value', file.path);
            }
        }

        // **************************************************************

        //MODELO 2 (comentado por aí) = ISSO TAMBÉM NÃO... ???? ****
         var files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
          //ISSO SERIA O PATH DA IMAGEM SENDO ATRIBUIDO NO FORMULÁRIO, #SOQUENAO
         form.find('[file]').attr('value', files[0].path);
        // **************************************************************


        // var form = $('#upload'); 

        // var reader = new FileReader();

        // reader.onload = function (event) {
        //     console.log('target', event.target.result);
        //     form.find('[file]').attr('value', event.target.result);
        // };

        // reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

          var progress = $('.progress');
          var bar = $('.progress-bar');
          var percent = $('.percent');
          var status = $('#error_display_op1');

          var options = {
              dataType: 'json',
              type:'post',
              resetForm:true,
              clearForm:true,
              beforeSend: function () {
                  $scope.enableSelectionShapes();
                  $('#moldal_progress').modal("show");
                  //cadastrarAlunosNaTurma();
                  progress
                      .removeClass('hide')
                      .show();
                  status.empty();
                  var percentVal = '0%';
                  bar.width(percentVal);
                  percent.html(percentVal);
              },
              uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                  var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                  bar.attr('aria-valuenow', percentComplete);
                  bar.width(percentVal);
                  percent.html(percentVal);
                  //
              },
              success: function () {
                  var percentVal = '100%';
                  bar.width(percentVal);
                  percent.html(percentVal);
                  $('#moldal_progress').modal("hide");
              },
              complete: function (xhr, errors, frm) {
                //  console.log(xhr);
                  // $(input).val('');
                  if (xhr.responseJSON) {
                      if (xhr.responseJSON.status) {

                          var file = xhr.responseJSON.filename;
                          var dir = xhr.responseJSON.directory;

                          if (angular.isDefined(file)) {
                              var data = dir + file;


                              fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
                                  img.scaleToWidth(200);
                                  img.scaleToHeight(200);

                                  if ($scope.is_mobile) {
                                      var left = 80, top = 80;
                                  } else {
                                      var left = 380, top = ($scope.canvasShape.getHeight() / 2) - 150;
                                  }
                                  img.set({
                                      left: left,
                                      top: top,
                                      angle: 0
                                  });

                                  var oImg = img;


                                  $scope.canvasShape.add(oImg).renderAll();
                                  var a = $scope.canvasShape.setActiveObject(oImg);
                                  var dataURL = $scope.canvasShape.toDataURL({
                                      format: 'png',
                                      multiplier: 4
                                  });
                              });


                          } else {
                              loadingOff();
                              status.empty();
                              var percentVal = '0%';
                              bar.width(percentVal);
                              percent.html(percentVal);
                              $rootScope.toastMessage("danger", "Erro de envio", xhr.responseJSON, 4000);

                          }
                      } else {
                          loadingOff();
                          // status.empty();
                          $rootScope.toastMessage("danger", "Erro de envio", "Não foi possível processar este arquivo.", 4000);


                          var percentVal = '0%';
                          bar.width(percentVal);
                          percent.html(percentVal);
                      }
                  }
              }
          };

          form.ajaxSubmit(options);
      }

      function handleDragOver(evt) {
        dropZone.classList.remove('is-dragging');
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
      }


  ['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(function(e){
    dropZone.addEventListener(e, handleDragOver, false)
  });

  ['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(function(e){
    dropZone.addEventListener(e, handleFileSelect, false)
  });

}
```

**PHP Zend 1.12:**

1) Controller:

```
public function uploadAutoriaAction()
{

    $postData = $this->apiPutData();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if (!empty($postData->token)) {
        if (!empty($postData->csrf_token)) {
            $request->setParam('csrf_token', $postData->csrf_token);
        }
        $request->setParam('token', $postData->token);

    }

    $filterAccessXSSOrigin = new Application_Model_Filter_XSSSecurityAccessOrigin(__FUNCTION__);
    $checkOrigin = $filterAccessXSSOrigin->accessControlAllowOrigin();
    if ($checkOrigin) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $checkOrigin");
        $this->authenticateJson($request);
    }
    $params = $request->getParams();

    $srvApi = new Application_Model_Service_GerenciarUploads();
    $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
    $result = $srvApi->uploadAutoria($upload);

    echo Zend_Json::encode($result);

}
```

2) Model:

```
public function uploadAutoria($upload)
{

    try {

        $size = 8388608; //8MB
        $megas = ($size / 1024 / 1024) . 'MB';
        $directory = $this->folder_imgs_autoria;

        $extensions = 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif';

        $permission_ext = explode(',', $extensions);
        $upload->setDestination($directory);
       // $upload->addFilter('LowerCase', null, 'arquivo');
        $upload->addValidator('Size', false, $size);
        $upload->addValidator('Extension', false, $extensions);
        $originalFilename = $upload->getFileName(null, false);
        $upload->clearFilters();

        $files = $upload->getFileInfo();

        $ext = strrchr($upload->getFileName(), '.');

        $filename = 'autoria_image_' .rand(0, 9999999999) . $ext;

        if (file_exists($upload->getFileName())) {
            throw new Zend_File_Transfer_Exception("Ocorreu um erro de duplicidade, tenter enviar novamente o arquivo.");
        }

        if ($upload->getFileSize() > $size) {
            throw new Zend_File_Transfer_Exception("O tamanho do arquivo é muito grande, não deve exceder o limite de {$megas}.");
        }
        $extension_file = str_replace('.', '', $ext);
        if (!in_array($extension_file, $permission_ext)) {
            throw new Zend_File_Transfer_Exception("O formato do arquivo não é suportado.");

        }
        $upload->addFilter('Rename', 'large_'.$filename, $upload->getFileName());
        // This takes care of the moving and making sure the file is there

        $date = new \DateTime();

        if (!$upload->receive()) {
            $messages = $upload->getMessages();
            $throw = implode("\n", $messages);
            throw new Zend_File_Transfer_Exception($throw);
        }

        //resize image
        $status = $this->resizeImage($directory . 'large_'.$filename, $directory . $filename,  723, 723);

        if ($status) {
            //remove o arquivo maior
            if(file_exists($directory . 'large_'.$filename)) {
                unlink($directory . 'large_'.$filename);
            }
        }


        $arrayInfo = array(
            'original_file' => $originalFilename,
            'data_upload' => $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'),
            'url_file' => $upload->getFileName(null, false),
            'message' => 'Arquivo enviado com sucesso!',
            'filename' => $filename,
            'directory' => '/'. FOLDER_ADM . '/uploader/files/autoria/imgs/',
            'type' => 'image_autoria',
            'status' => true
        );

    } catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
        $arrayInfo = array(
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        );
    }

    return $arrayInfo;
}
```

> **Obs:** Sem dúvida, é maior que um Problema XY, eu quero o X, mas o X não parece ser um caminho válido, ou seja, eu preciso encontrar uma solução... Como desta maneira não funciona, pois seria uma falha de segurança ter acesso ao arquivo, deve haver uma outra alternativa, pois o que preciso no final é enviar o arquivo para o servidor (depois de soltá-lo na tela).
>
> Uma maneira que estava tentando fazer é herdando um método que já era funcional onde clico num botão sob um formulário escondido, que envio o arquivo para a minha área de edição, através de um formulário simples de upload, o ajax, faz o resto dos efeitos a partir desse clique, quando a imagem recebe através do evento "change", ocorre o "loading" com um CSS de progresso, etc. Que por sua vez, é exibido quando o arquivo de imagem ainda não foi carregado, a ideia é capturar este mesmo evento, quando uma imagem é arrastada para dentro da minha área de edição, e salvar este link com a mesmas características de renome do arquivo que será salvo no servidor...

Comment: A origem que você cita seria o caminho da imagem no computador do usuário?

Comment: Exato @AndersonCarlosWoss, eu queria pegar o path da imagem quando soltar o arquivo...

Comment: Então não é possível. Isso seria uma grande brecha de segurança por expor informações do computador do usuário. Por que precisa disso?

Comment: Para enviar o arquivo no upload, e ter o endereçamento dele no servidor. Não pode ser base64... preciso ter ele como arquivo.

Comment: Para enviar no upload não precisa saber a origem, no momento que você arrasta para o navegador ele cuida do que é preciso. Por que precisa saber qual é o caminho do arquivo no usuário se o upload será feito no servidor?

Comment: Eu não preciso saber, só preciso colocar ele no input do formulário em ajax e enviar como tipo file...

Comment: Em tese, eu até poderia criar ele no servidor, salvando esse base64 como um arquivo, mas eu preciso recuperar ele e salvar no mesmo formato que eu faço o upload.

Comment: Isso é um [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499), o upload de arquivos via drag'n'drop não funciona dessa forma, tampouco o input de arquivos aceita caminhos. O Path do file upload é mera visualização para facilitar a vida do usuário. Seria importante [edit] o problema refletindo a necessidade real, e não a maneira como acha que daria certo.

Comment: Então o problema consiste em fazer o upload ao soltar o arquivo na página? Se sim, não vejo porque colocar a parte do PHP na pergunta. Pode limitá-la a conseguir fazer a requisição HTTP que envia o arquivo com JavaScript através dos eventos de drag-n-drop. Se o lado do PHP também não está funcionando como deveria, talvez seria uma questão para outra pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade, o php está lá só para mostrar como ele recebe o arquivo. Pois deve ter maneiras de tratar no php e enviar o base64,  converter e salvar esse arquivo na pasta acredito eu.